# Sitecore, How do you add a link or image map to the home slides?

Tags: sitecore, slideshow, imagemap

my company has this project, the digital media specialist gave me a design which has 4 other pictures on the main slide. I have use the home slider group and create new item for it.

In the home slider template, I can enter some text and it will float over the slide (in short description), but I would like to know how to either make a image maps for these 4 pictures or give a link when they click on the slide?

I am enable to either disable the floating text box and give different css style to it.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore doesn't have a 'slider' control, so this is probably something the original developers designed and developed.

Unfortunately for you, it doesn't sound like the implementation meets your new business requirements.  I believe you'd have to update your code in order to accomplish what you're trying to do via the Content or Page Editor.

Comment: For @Chia_Tea's benefit, I think it's worth making it clear that in most modern CMS's the widgets (components, plugins, whatever you call them) aren't really part of the core product. They are add-ons made by developers. This situation is by no means unique to Sitecore.